# Multiple interfaces in a java class - which gets used for method calls?

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have a class that implements two interfaces and I send that class to an overloaded method that accepts either interface; which variant of the method will be called?

In other words, if I have something like this:

```
interface A {}
interface B {}

class C implements A, B { }

class D
{
    public static void doThings(A thing){ System.out.println("handling A");}
    public static void doThings(B thing){ System.out.println("handling B");}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThings(new C());
    }
}
```

And I send my class C to the method/s in D:

```
doThings(C);
```

Which method should be called? Does the Java standard cover this?

Comment: It does. What did it do when you tried it?

Comment: There can only be one method with a given signature.

Comment: I updated your code a little. Instead of asking us try to run it and see how Java will react.

Comment: I think you will get a compile error.

Comment: I mean, what happened to actually trying things out before asking?

Comment: To avoid the error, you can cast `C`: `doThings((A) new C());`.

Comment: -1 Not sure why you would ask this, you can easily try it and answer your own question. Also, it's not difficult to find the relevant sections in the standard.

Comment: `I send my class C to the method in D` It all depends on what you are using as reference. If you use `A a = new C()` and use `doThings(a)` then `doThings(A thing)` will be invoked despite fact that you are passing instance of `C`. But if you pass reference of type `C` then you will not be able to compile your code because of  `method doThings is ambiguous ...` error.

Comment: Oh, I did try and got a compiler error. Which is what I expected. I was just trying to work out how the compiler/spec dealt with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will get a compiler error, because multiple methods match, namely, both `doThings` methods.

The JLS does cover this, in [Section 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).  It covers how to resolve which method is applicable for an expression that calls a method.

> Otherwise, we say that the method invocation is ambiguous, and a compile-time error occurs.

This occurs after multiple methods are found that match, one method is not any more "specific" than another, and none are `abstract`.

Comment: I was just about to post this, +1.

Comment: As additional information, in case we want to explicitly invoke variant handling `A` or `B` we can either use reference of type we are interested in, or just use casing like `doThings((B)new C());`.

Answer (score 6):

This raises a compile time error.
"The method doThings is ambiguous for the type D"
So this is your answer.

```
interface AAA { }
interface BBB { }

class C implements AAA, BBB {  }

public class D
{
    public static void doThings(AAA thing){

    }
    public static void doThings(BBB thing){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        C x = new C();
        D.doThings(x);
    }
}
```

Here is the exact error:

```
C:\Programs\eclipse\workspace\TEST\src>javac D.java
D.java:17: reference to doThings is ambiguous, both method doThings(AAA) in D and method doThings(BBB) in D match
        D.doThings(x);
         ^
1 error
```

***Still, note that if you define x as `AAA x = new C();`

or as `BBB x = new C();`, then it compiles OK. Now

the type of the `x` reference (AAA or BBB) makes

this version unambiguous.***

Comment: I agree with this poster ... this should result in a compile error since Java is statically typed and this results in ambiguity

Answer (score 3):

It will give you a compile time error: "The method doThings(A) is ambiguous for the type D".

To fix this instead of calling

`doThings(new C());`

you can call

**`doThings((A)new C());`**

or

**`doThings((B)new C());`**

Answer (score 2):

It is a `compile time error`. Not even runtime, a compile time error.

[This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) clearly explains.

`It is possible for a class to inherit more than one field with the same name. Such a situation does not in itself cause a compile-time error. However, any attempt within the body of the class to refer to any such field by its simple name will result in a compile-time error, because such a reference is ambiguous.`

This is exactly what you tried to do.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the folks that are stating this will result in a Java Compile Time Error.

It is important to note that Java is a statically typed language -- what that means for this case is that: which methods will be invoked (in this case) will be determined at compile time.

There are exceptions to this rule -- for example when method invocation by reflection.

So in this case when the compiler tries to determine which method to bind the call to -- it will be forced into an ambiguous situation -- resulting a compile time error.